# Bootstrap dropdown: events for the 'navbar-toggle'?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Do we have **events** for the `navbar-toggle` that appears when we are on the smaller screen?

For instance,

```
$('#myDropdown').on('shown.bs.navbar-toggle', function () {
  // do something…
});

$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.navbar-toggle', function () {
  // do something…
});
```

html,

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>-->
</div>
```

Otherwise, how can we detect if that `navbar-toggle` exists on the smaller screen?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The `navbar-toggle` methods emit the Collapse events:

## Events

Bootstrap's collapse class exposes a few events for hooking into collapse functionality.

```
Event Type           Description
show.bs.collapse     This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
shown.bs.collapse    This event is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to     the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).
hide.bs.collapse     This event is fired immediately when the hide method has been called. 
hidden.bs.collapse   This event is fired when a collapse element has been hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).
```

## Example

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: I could not get this event to fire (not in Chrome at least), see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43288718/759673) workaround that solved the problem.

Comment: for bootstrap 4 https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#via-javascript

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get the show/shown or hide/hidden.bs.collapse events to be triggered. I tied the event to the #navbar element.

What did work for me was just using the *resize* event and then check if the navbar is visible:

Combining what @Patel, [madhatter160](http://jsfiddle.net/madhatter160/ubeevquh/) and @haxxxton suggested I was able to get it to work:

```
var navbar_visible = $("#navbar").is(":visible");

$(window).resize(function(){
  navbar_visible = $("#navbar").is(":visible");

  if (navbar_visible)
    $('#brand_name').text('Navbar is visible');
  else
    $('#brand_name').text('Navbar is not visible');
});
```

This is a pretty simple solution that doesn't need any special jQuery plugins to work. I wish it was possible to get this to work using the defined *.bs.collapse events though!

You can also try this our on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kashiraja/d1p33nc9/1/).

Comment: Just curious, was the element `#navbar` injected via ajax after the initial page load? That could explain why the `.on` event didn't work as is. It is not optimal to hook into the `.resize` method if possible as it will cause a lot of overhead on the page, especially while someone is resizing their browser window.

Comment: I forked your jsfiddle to use the correct bootstrap events and it's working just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/j4j7tgz2/

Comment: @EricUldall (1): The id="navbar" is on line 13. I agree that you get a lot of events, but possible to use a timeout to limit to say process only after each 100 ms. (2): That's interesting... I can't get your fiddle to work in my browser! (Chrome 57 on Win7). But the one I posted still works on my end. Some compatibility issues...

Comment: Interesting. I've run the fiddle in Chrome 58.0.3029.110 on MacOS (Sierra). Unfortunately I don't have a good way to test it on your current architecture and provide more detailed info. It's really unfortunate because it is the optimal scenario to use the events provided by the library. Perhaps if someone is interested they could post a ticket at the bootstrap.js github issues and see if they know of some compatibility issue.

Comment: for show.bs.collapse make to work, you should tie the event handler to $("div.navbar-collapse.collapse")

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery you can test if something is visible using `.is(':visible')`. http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

If you need its visibility to trigger something else you could look at implementing the jQuery Mutate plugin. This effectively monitors an element for a change in a property and then fires an event. http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/

Comment: The problem with this method is that it's not event driven. You either have to be constantly checking the visibility of the element or hook into some other chatty event on the page (ie: resize, see comments on @kashiraja 's answer)