# Bootstrap 3: Catch event when navbar is collapsed or expanded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3:

Is it possible to catch when the navbar is collapsed/expanded?

I can't seam to find an event for this.

Edit:

I have a logo that is 90px heigh, so the navbar must be around 110px heigh.

To place the menu links close to the main content, I therefor have a margin-top at 60px. When it collapse, I want the three dashes (icon-bar) to have a margin-top of 60px also. When doing that, the menu suddently is 60px + 60px = 120px down - and that is 60px too much.  So I want to catch when it's collapsed and then change margin-top of menu-links to 0px and when it's expanded I want to change it to 60px.

Here's a bootply sample:

http://www.bootply.com/120802

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap dropdown: events for the 'navbar-toggle'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900326/bootstrap-dropdown-events-for-the-navbar-toggle)

Comment: Like this ? https://www.bootply.com/8BmYmaaeav#
OMG 2014 :D lol my bad

Answer (score 18):

Maybe this way:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
// do something
});
```

The navbar is using the collapse jQuery-Plugin. There you can look for the events: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Edit:
I added an example of usage:
http://jsbin.com/tizanoti/4/edit

Comment: Can you plz share the relevant part of your code to see why this doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your sample, but I don't want to know when the button is clicked. I need to catch when the menu is collapsed/expanded (changed from the menu-links to the three-dashes-button).

Comment: I don't see any problem in your example code. Just do something in your function (http://www.bootply.com/120826#).
And I don't catch the button click event in my example. Just the collapsed event.

Comment: Now I get what you want. You can achieve this by getting the viewport width. There is also an event 'resize' where you can catch a change on the viewport. The navbar will show per default in bootstrap with a viewport size of 768px. Later, I can show you an example of that. but you can also do it with css media query

Comment: You cannot use viewport width reliably, because there is some hysteresis; the transition point is different when going from wide to narrow vs narrow to wide viewport. [See this answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900326/bootstrap-dropdown-events-for-the-navbar-toggle).

Answer (score 7):

Enable manually with:

```
$('.collapse').collapse()
```

Collapse Methods

```
.collapse("toggle") //Toggles the collapsible element   
.collapse("show")   //Shows the collapsible element 
.collapse("hide")   //Hides the collapsible element
```

Collapse Events

```
show.bs.collapse    //Occurs when the collapsible element is about to be shown
shown.bs.collapse   //Occurs when the collapsible element is fully shown (after CSS transitions have completed)
hide.bs.collapse    //Occurs when the collapsible element is about to be hidden
hidden.bs.collapse  //Occurs when the collapsible element is fully hidden (after CSS transitions have completed)
```

[reference](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Collapse Methods of bootstrap cab be used to detect these collapse/expand event. document.ready is included so that this evaluation happens only after a page is loaded safely

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
   alert('shown'); 
 });

 $('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
   alert('hidden'); 
 });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I get it. Add this to your css:

```
.navbar-collapse { margin-top: 0; }
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .navbar-collapse { margin-top: 60px; }
}
```

Edit: changed for usage in pure css without less-variables.

Comment: the above piece of code is written in less, for css you have to replace '@screen-sm-min' with '768px'

Comment: If a future bootstrap version changes the 768 to something different, this breaks.  A callback or at least introspection would be more robust.

Comment: You cannot use viewport width reliably, because there is some hysteresis; the transition point is different when going from wide to narrow vs narrow to wide viewport. See [this answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43288718/759673). (Initially I put this comment under the above post, but belongs here...)