# Bootstrap .navbar-toggle event

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 3 to make a responsive site.  I am using their [Dashboard](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) example as a starting point.

The example has a breakpoint at 768px so that the top navigation bar goes from a "hamburger" menu button to a horizontal list of navigation items.  I need to somehow react when that breakpoint is reached.

Based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900326/bootstrap-dropdown-events-for-the-navbar-toggle) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318672/bootstrap-3-catch-event-when-navbar-is-collapsed-or-expanded), I've tried to bind to the show/hide.bs.collapse events on the button element to no avail.  Is there a way to bind to an event or somehow listen for when the breakpoint is reached?

I've set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhatter160/ubeevquh/) with the relevant parts (move the vertical slider to get the navbar to change).  Here's the JavaScript I've tried:

```
$( ".navbar-toggle" ).on( "show.bs.collapse", function() {
    alert( "hamburger show" );
} )
.on( "hide.bs.collapse", function() {
    alert( "hamburger hide" );
} );
```

Comment: try $(window).resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a neat solution I read about recently, that has worked really well for cases like this: https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries

Basically you use jQuery to test for CSS rules that apply only to specific breakpoints. So for example, if you wanted to fire something at 768px when your hamburger is set to disappear, and you had some CSS written that uses media queries, you could do something like:

```
<h1>Example</h1>

h1 { font-size: 15px; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    h1 { font-size: 30px; }
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    var example = $('h1');
    if (example.css('font-size') == '30px') {
        alert('breakpoint');
    }

});
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hq651vjy/2/

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of window.resize...sheesh.  The trick with detecting the change by looking at the CSS is a great idea. I was able to check if the "display" style of the .navbar-toggle was "none".  Thanks!!

Comment: This is another [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43288718/759673) that just checks the "is visible" property.

Answer (score 2):

Not related to breakpoints but related to Google keyword search:  This worked for me on version 4.6.x of Bootstrap:

```
$(".navbar-collapse").on("show.bs.collapse", function () {
        alert("hamburger show");
    })
    .on("hide.bs.collapse", function () {
        alert("hamburger hide");
});
```

Comment: Working nicely on Bootstrap 5 thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a breakpoint, you can listen to `resize` event and then do what you want to do with it.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if($(window).width() == 768) {
     //do something
    console.log('Gotcha!');
    }  
});
```

This type of solution would work if user doesn't resize the window too quickly. Let me know if this works for you.